# Angular clarity design not to lazy load tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, vmware-clarity, clarity

I would need the not to lazy load the tabs with the clarity tab component,
and be able to switch between the tabs programatically.
The problem is if I appy the the directive mentioned it the docs [(clrIfActive)] the contetnt gets lazy loaded.
Here is the documentation:https://v2.clarity.design/tabs

Comment: So you *don't* want to lazy load the tabs?

Comment: Please add more detail to this question - including @NicholasK 's comment - why do you want to avoid lazy loading? Is there a fundamental reason you wish to omit it, such as an issue with passing data around? What have you tried so far?

Comment: From the link you posted `The tabs component uses the *clrIfActive structural directive to lazy load the content of an active tab.` Leaving it out should fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want lazy loading, include the `*clrIfActive` directive in the `clr-tab-content` component markup, for example:

```
        <clr-tab-content id="content1" *clrIfActive>
        ...
        </clr-tab-content>
```

If you don't want lazy loading, leave `*clrIfActive` out.

Comment: This way how is it posibble to programatically select the active tabs?

Comment: You will have to add template references to the tab link directive and use the activate fn manually: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/layout/tabs/tab-link.directive.ts#L95